# Sticky Conveyor Belt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm working on having a sticky conveyor belt, so that objects can also go around it. But my objects currently get stuck half way, as seen in the picture.

[image]

This is the movement code of the conveyor belt.

```
private void HandleCargo()
{
    var _speed = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    foreach (var cargo in _cargo)
    {
        var change = cargo.Key.transform.right * _speed;
        cargo.Key.transform.Translate(change);
    }
}
```

And the code taking care of the rotation to the surface.

```
private void Update()
{
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, -transform.up, Color.black);

    if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out var hit, _distance)) return;
    var normal = hit.normal;

    transform.up -= (transform.up - hit.normal) * 0.05f;
}
```

If someone has pointers as to why this happens, that would be great. I kind of have an idea, since the transform right of the conveyor code is pointing inwards at this angles so the movement doesn't happen around the belt anymore, but I exhausted my attempts to fix it...

Comment: How many items are in _cargo?  You will stop when the number of items run out.  So you scaling need to be a function of the number of items.

Comment: For now its just one and it might always just stay one. The number doesn't run out in this case. I don't see how this is relevant for the movement and rotation though.

Comment: It looks like your `change` value is relative to the transform (you use `transform.right`), and then you apply it again relatively in the `Translate` function (which defaults to `Space.Self`), so that may be one relative too many. Try either multiplying `_speed` by `Vector3.right` instead of `transform.right`, or adding `Space.World` as `Translate's` second parameter.

Comment: For reference, this question has been [crossposted to here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/179710/sticky-conveyor-belt) where it received an answer (the same resolve as my comment).